# Trying to render parent object in registered helper

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

Here is my JS:

```
UI.registerHelper('editor', function(doc){
  var html = ' <div class="form-group">';
  html += '<label class="control-label">Content</label>';
  // html += '<textarea rows="5" name="content" class="form-control" id="postContent" required data-schema-key="content">' + doc.content + '</textarea>';
  html += '</div>';

  console.log(doc);

  return Spacebars.SafeString(html);
});
```

Template:

```
<template name="postForm">
  {{#autoForm collection="Posts" id=formId type=action validation="submit" doc=.. }}
    {{> afQuickField name='slug' }}
    {{> afQuickField name='title' }}

    {{editor ../..}}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{submitBtn}}</button>
  {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

In my `console.log` this is what is printed:

```
Document.(anonymous function) {_id: "JMZRMiMgvX3WxPFSc", slug: "test", title: "test", content: "werwer", user_id: "qQu4RurcQPqN5CP3R"…}
_id: "JMZRMiMgvX3WxPFSc"
content: "werwer"
createdAt: "2014-05-02T15:41:48.458Z"
slug: "test"
title: "test"
user_id: "qQu4RurcQPqN5CP3R"
```

I'm not too sure what the `Document.(anonymous function)` is, but all I need to do is access the content from the parent and use it in my helper.

*Edit*
Here is the code I got to work

JavaScript:

```
UI.registerHelper('editor', function(context, options){
  var content = (context !== 'undefined') ? context : null;
  var html = ' <div class="form-group">';
  html += '<label class="control-label">Content</label>';
  html += '<textarea rows="5" name="content" class="form-control" id="postContent" required data-schema-key="content">' + content + '</textarea>';
  html += '</div>';

  if(content) {
    var editor = $('#postContent').wysihtml5();
    editor.data("wysihtml5").editor.setValue(content);
  }

  return Spacebars.SafeString(html);
});
```

Template:

```
<template name="postForm">
  {{#autoForm collection="Posts" id=formId type=action validation="submit" doc=.. }}
    {{> afQuickField name='slug' }}
    {{> afQuickField name='title' }}

    {{{editor ../../content}}}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{submitBtn}}</button>
  {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

Comment: Does `doc.content` not work? Why is that line commented out? (By the way, generating HTML in a helper is probably a bad idea, and you should rather make `editor` a template. If `content` is user input, this is a security problem.)

Comment: `doc.content` didn't work... I had to do `../../content` for it to work. I updated my question with working code... can you shed some light on what I am doing wrong?